# AcceptVerbsAttribute in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I need to write an action method which should respond to both Http get and Http post verbs in asp.net core MVC.I tried the following but it did not work and actually the acceptverbs attribute does not accept `HttpVerbs.Get` | `HttpVerbs.Post`) as it would do in **MVC 5**. So can someone help with this?

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public IActionResult BatchGroupDetails(int id)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this way? It works for me.

```
[HttpPost()]
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]`

I have it set up like this to not use too many lines of code.